# Is it best using GStreamer to generate a pipeline automatically thanks to gst_parse_launch() or manually?

Tags: pipeline, gstreamer

Currently developing an application with GStreamer on an embedded device, I was asking myself whether there is or not a significant difference in using the `gst_parse_launch()` function to generate my pipeline rather than doing it manually. Indeed, following this link I got a partial answer on a use case: [Limitations of gst_parse_launch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100967/limitations-of-gst-parse-launch).

However, am I right thinking that we could still access to the different elements thanks to the `gst_bin_get_by_name()` function which then enables us to manually link their pads after an automatic generation of my pipeline? Has `gst_parse_launch()` got any drawbacks that I'm not thinking of?

As I am searching for the best possible performance (memory consumption / process time), I find this automation process interesting as it might do exactly the same thing while shortening the code.